# About assignment by reference and value in JAVA

Tags: java

#### Case 1

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dog aDog = new Dog()
    Dog oldDog = new Dog()
if(aDog== oldDog) {
  System.out.println("Same");
} else {
  System.out.println("Different");
}

}
```

Output: Different

#### Case 2

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dog aDog = new Dog();
    Dog oldDog = aDog;

if(aDog== oldDog) {
  System.out.println("Same");
} else {
  System.out.println("Different");
}

}
```

Output: Same

Can someone explain to me the result of these programs, please?

Comment: This question is very vague. Please include more detail and ask a **specific question**. You may wish to revise this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Also, please introduce your question before posting any code.

Comment: Can you attempt to explain in your own words what the line `oldDog = aDog` does?

Answer (score 1):

- The first case creates two different `Objects`, each one with its own reference/entity in memory. *Instances from the same Class, but different Objects anyway.*
- In the second case, you assign the same `Object` reference to the new `Dog` instance: **they both refer to the same `Object`.**

**The `==` operator compares the references of objects.** In your second case, they both reference the same `Dog`.

*This is for `Objects`, not primitives; Regarding primitives, the value itself is compared.*

---

*Java Specification  [Equality Operators:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.21)*

> If the operands of an equality operator are both of either reference
> type or the null type, then the operation is object equality. A
> compile-time error occurs if it is impossible to convert the type of
> either operand to the type of the other by a casting conversion
> (§5.5). The run-time values of the two operands would necessarily be
> unequal.
>
> **At run time, the result of == is true if the operand values are both null or both refer to the same object or array; otherwise, the result
> is false.**

Comment: "Memory address" is usually a misleading concept to introduce when discussing the JVM; the Java documentation generally simply sticks with "the same/identical object".

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- agreed, coming from c world this is somehow misleading. I updated the answer, hope it's cleaner now. Thanks for the comment!